# I want to save some data to some sort of offline database

Tags: android, database

So I have 2 EditText fields with some text which I want to save and load in a later date. What is the best approach in doing it? It must be saved on the phone and not on an online internet database(Like Firebase).

**Solutions I have thought of are:**

**1. Save it in a single text file with the .txt extension removed.**

```
a. Here I will use keywords which my code can read like <START OF DATA(x)> 
   where x is the id of the data saved.(

b. This obviously will take a long time to implement but it will make. But 
   will be a lot neater than solution #2.
```

**2. Save each result to separate text file with the .txt extension removed.**
    a. Here I will save results to their corresponding text file(Ex: res0001).

```
b. I will use a third party file explorer to load the text contained in the 
   text file.

c. This is easier to implement than solution #1.
```

Any other suggestions on how to best approach my problem? An API perhaps?

Comment: Look at SharedPreferences or SQLite

Comment: Use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)

Comment: SharedPreferences.

Comment: @Lex F see my answer

Comment: If I close the app then open it again. Does SharedPreferences still have the data?

Comment: Thank you guys all the answers were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex_F you can use the SharedPreferences but if user clear the app data or cache of your application from setting then your SharedPreferences gives the default value rather than your actual saved value.For permanent storage, you can use the SQLite database but SQLite required more boilerplate code.I think you should try to use the realm database which is very simple to use.This up to you which database should use.But I would give the example of real database like.

```
public class UserInformation extends RealmObject {

private String name;
@PrimaryKey  //define the phone number as a primary key
private String phone;
private String address;
private String gmail;

public UserInformation() {
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getGmail() {
    return gmail;
}

public void setGmail(String gmail) {
    this.gmail = gmail;
}

}
```

Now in the any activity

```
Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Realm.init(this);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();


    //insert the data into the realm database
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        //second argument represent the primary key
                        UserInformation information = realm.createObject(UserInformation.class, phone.getText().toString());
                        information.setName(name.getText().toString());
                        information.setGmail(email.getText().toString());
                       information.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
                        realm.copyToRealm(information);

                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully inserted data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wrong please try again later..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

            }
    });

    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        RealmResults<UserInformation> query = realm.where(UserInformation.class).equalTo("phone", phone.getText().toString()).findAll();
                        //if query not gives any result then query.size() return give 0 value
                        if (query.size() == 0) {
                            ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "You entered wrong information or might be your entered phone no not matches existing information");
                        } else {
                            for (UserInformation info : query) {
                                info.setName(name.getText().toString());
                              //  info.setPhone(phone.getText().toString());
                                info.setGmail(email.getText().toString());
                                info.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
                                realm.copyToRealm(info);
                            }
                            ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "Successfully updated data");
                        }
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "Your Information Updated Successfully..");

                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    clearData();
                    ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "Your Information not Updated something wrong...");
                    ToastLogUtil.errorlog(error.toString());
                }
            });

        }
    });

     retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText().toString()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(address.getText().toString())) {
                //at this you can retrieve all information 
                RealmResults<UserInformation> query = realm.where(UserInformation.class).findAllAsync();
                for (UserInformation info : query) {
                    text.append(info.getName() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getPhone() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getGmail() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getAddress() + "\n");
                }
                ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this,"retrieve all data successfully...");
            } else {
                //at this query you can retrieve specific user which have a same phone which you enter in .equalTO() method
                RealmResults<UserInformation> query = realm.where(UserInformation.class).equalTo("phone", phone.getText().toString()).findAll();
                for (UserInformation info : query) {
                    text.append(info.getName() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getPhone() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getGmail() + "\n");
                    text.append(info.getAddress() + "\n");
                    ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this,"Retrieve "+info.getPhone()+ " data successfully...");
                }
            }
        }
    });


     delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText().toString())) {
                ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "Please mention the phone number you want to delete");
            } else {

                RealmResults<UserInformation> query = realm.where(UserInformation.class).equalTo("phone", phone.getText().toString()).findAllAsync();
                if (query.size() == 0) {
                     ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this,"Your phone no not matches in our database phone no..");
                } else {
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    query.deleteAllFromRealm();
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                    ToastLogUtil.toastmessage(MainActivity.this, "Delete data successfully...");
                }
            }
        }
    });

   }
```

Thank you :-)

Not forget to add the realm dependencies

//Add the class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
}
```

}

//Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of the application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks for introducing me to Realm!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the value in Preferences. Below class will be make easy for you to save data and retrive it from Preferences

```
public class SessionManager {

    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private static SessionManager sessionManager;




    public static SessionManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(sessionManager == null){
            sessionManager = new SessionManager(context);
        }
        return sessionManager;
    }


    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        String PREF_NAME = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        this.pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }


    /**
     * Getting value for key from shared Preferences
     *
     * @param key          key for which we need to get Value
     * @param defaultValue default value to be returned if key is not exits
     * @return It will return value of key if exist and defaultValue otherwise
     */
    public String getValueFromKey(String key, String defaultValue) {
        if (pref.containsKey(key)) {
            return pref.getString(key, defaultValue);
        } else {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Setting value for key from shared Preferences
     *
     * @param key   key for which we need to get Value
     * @param value value for the key
     */
    public void setValueFromKey(String key, String value) {
        pref.putString(key, value).apply();
    }


    /**
     * Setting value for key from shared Preferences
     *
     * @param key   key for which we need to get Value
     * @param value value for the key
     */
    public void setFlagFromKey(String key, boolean value) {
        pref.putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }


    /**
     * To get Flag from sharedPreferences
     *
     * @param key key of flag to get
     * @return flag value for key if exist. false if not key not exist.
     */
    public boolean getFlagFromKey(String key) {
        return pref.containsKey(key) && pref.getBoolean(key, false);
    }

}
```