# Android Studio: Unable to create another RealmObject

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

So I am working on creating this application and I already created a class with RealmObject. However, Whenever I try to create another class, My application stops working. This only happens with I try to create a class that extends RealmObject. It doesn't happen any other way. I already have a class that uses RealmObject tho. Also, I checked logcat, It didn't throw any error message.. What do i do?
this is `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.abc.apps">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".profiles" />
            <activity android:name=".view_profile" />
            <activity android:name=".EditProfile" />
            <activity android:name=".Quiz" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

here is `build.gradle (project: apps)` :-

```
        buildscript {

            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
            }
            dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
                classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0"
                // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
                // in the individual module build.gradle files
            }
        }

        allprojects {
            repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
            }
        }

        task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
        }
```

here is build.gradle (Module:app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    android {

        compileSdkVersion 26
        configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9' }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.abc.apps"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

and here is my RealmObject class that causes errors:-

```
    import io.realm.RealmObject;

    /**
     * Created by Admin on 4/5/2018.
     */

    public class showdata extends RealmObject {
       String id;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show the code.Because it's difficult to say anything without the Code.

Comment: @RishabhRawat Ok one second I will edit it in

Comment: @RishabhRawat I added

Comment: Please give the error name because your code is totally correct.If your device show the ANR then check the log cat window.Because without any error how application stop working.

Comment: See my previous post. if you like then upvote because your problem might be solved in my previous post on realm database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880438/i-want-to-save-some-data-to-some-sort-of-offline-database/48881794#48881794

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because a database (realm) migration. 
You need first create a class that implements RealmMigration and overwrite migrate method.
the following code snippet is from realm [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest#migrations)

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
  @Override
  public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

     // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
     RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

     // Migrate to version 1: Add a new class.
     // Example:
     // public Person extends RealmObject {
     //     private String name;
     //     private int age;
     //     // getters and setters left out for brevity
     // }
     if (oldVersion == 0) {
        schema.create("Person")
            .addField("name", String.class)
            .addField("age", int.class);
        oldVersion++;
     }

     // Migrate to version 2: Add a primary key + object references
     // Example:
     // public Person extends RealmObject {
     //     private String name;
     //     @PrimaryKey
     //     private int age;
     //     private Dog favoriteDog;
     //     private RealmList<Dog> dogs;
     //     // getters and setters left out for brevity
     // }
     if (oldVersion == 1) {
        schema.get("Person")
            .addField("id", long.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
            .addRealmObjectField("favoriteDog", schema.get("Dog"))
            .addRealmListField("dogs", schema.get("Dog"));
        oldVersion++;
     }
  }
}
```

and in your application class ( extends Application ) you need to initiate a realm configuration object and setting realm default configuartion.

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .schemaVersion(2) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
    .migration(new MyMigration()) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
    .build()
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

finally, you need to reference your Application class that extends Application in your manifest like this:

```
<application
            android:name=".YOURAPPLICATIONCLASSNAME"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
.
.
.
</application>
```

Comment: @buffyBTVS96 are there any messages in logcat ?

Comment: No :/ do u think it would be okay if i send u my app and u can have a look at whats wrong.. I am so not getting it

Comment: upload it in git repository and send me a link to find out what's wrong.